# R- How to do a loop on a list and output different dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, rodbc

I'm attempting to create a loop in R that will use a vector of dates, run them through a loop that includes a SQL query, and then generate a separate dataframe for each output. Here is as far as I've gotten:

```
library(RODBC)

dvect <- as.Date("2015-04-13") + 0:2   
d <- list()
for(i in list(dvect)){

    queryData <- sqlQuery(myconn, paste("SELECT
        WQ_hour,
        sum(calls) as calls
        FROM database
        WHERE DDATE = '", i,"'
        GROUP BY 1
        ", sep = ""))

    d[i] <- rbind(d, queryData)
}
```

From what I can tell, the query portion of the code runs fine since I've tested it by itself. Where I'm stumbling is the last line where I try to save the contents of each loop through the query separately with each having a label of the date that was used in the loop.

I'd appreciate any help. I've only been using R consistently for about 2 months now so I'm definitely open to alternative ways of doing this that are cleaner and more efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you come across `lapply` yet?

Comment: @AkhilNair  I haven't. Is it a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I believe so. The point of apply functions is that they `apply` a function vector-wise so are much more efficient. In the case of `lapply`, the function is applied to elements held in a data structure (in your case a list, but this could be variable), and the `l` in `[l]apply` refers to the data being returned as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest making the SQL query a function, and use `lapply` to apply it and return your result as a list.

```
userSQLquery = function(i) {
  sqlQuery(myconn, paste("SELECT
          WQ_hour,
          sum(calls) as calls
          FROM database
          WHERE DDATE = '", i,"'
          GROUP BY 1
          ", sep = ""))
}

dvect = as.Date("2015-04-13") + 0:2    
d = as.list(1:length(dvect))
names(d) = dvect

lapply(d, userSQLquery)
```

I have very little experience with SQL though, so this may not work. Maybe it could start you off?

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
d[[i]] <- queryData
```

if you want each data.frame (query result) as a separate element in the list output `d`.

Or use:

```
d <- rbind(d, queryData)
```

if you want a single `data.frame` with all the query outputs combined. In this case you should declare `d` as a data.frame (i.e. `d <- data.frame()`).

You can also store each `data.frame` (i.e. the query result) with its corresponding date in a list as:

```
d[[i]] <- list(date = dvect[[i]], queryResult = queryData)
```

*I think the last one is what you are looking for.*

Comment: I haven't been able to get the first option to work so far. It's giving me a single vector of ~16000 null values. 

The second option right now is only giving me the results of the last query. I'll keep working at it

Comment: @William, the third option should produce your desired result, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for lapply [(lapply documentation)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html%20/%20R%20lapply%20documentation)instead of a for loop. (In R it's often good to avoid a for loop by using a vectorization.)

If you want each date to return a separate data frame, and then have each data frame labelled with the original date, try:

```
dates <- c("Jan 1", "Oct 31", "Dec 25")

queryData <- function(date){
#dummy data
  return(runif(5))
}

results <- lapply(dates, queryData)
names(results) <- dates
```